# compute number of step for composite simpson's rule in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the number of step size for my composite simpson's rule in matlab .. Here is my code

```
% Estimate the number of steps n required for the three point composite Simpson’s rule,
% function's integral from 0 to 1 and the function is ∫ 4/(1+x.^2)=pi within an error bound of 10−6
h=0.01;
n=1000;
x=pi;
a=0;
b=1;
x=zeros(1,n);
f=@(x)4./(1+x.^2);
nn=(b-a)/h;
xexact=integral(f,a,b);
p=0;
q=0;

for i=1:n
x(i)=a+(i-1)*h;
end

for i=1:n-1
    p=p+2*(f(x(i)))+4*(f(x(i)+h/2));
end

nn=((b-a)*(f(a)+f(a+h/2)+p+f(b)))./(6*x)
```

When I run the code I get a vector of 1 * 1000 elements but I want to get the number of steps which is `nn=(b-a)/h` .. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
nn=((b-a)*(f(a)+f(a+h/2)+p+f(b)))./(6*x)
```

In this piece of code you call for 'x' but 'x' is a 1x1000 double, so consequently your nn is a 1x1000 double.

Answer (score 0):

Igor's answer seems to be incorrect.
In your code `x` is a `1x1000 double`. All other values in `nn` are `1x1` double. 
When you use division you got:

```
1x1 double ./ 1x1000 double
```

So it returns `1x1000 doubles`

P.S. First of all, check your loop - it computes 999 times, but `p` IS NOT AN ARRAY. It contains only last value in this loop!
Secondary, you can't get single value using `x` array this way.

Comment: @AllieAls you have to give more information to us: I can't understand, what you want to achieve. If you want to get just `nn=(b-a)/h` then display `nn` before you overwrite it with your last formula. 
If you want something else, please clarify it in your question, and we'll try to help you! :)